# Zip and calculate

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I am looking for a solution without the use of recursion. I have 3 datas such as:

```
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David"]

-- their grades:
grades :: [[Int]]
grades = [[3, 2], [4, 6], [2, 3], [1, 4]]

-- And the weights for a total note
weights :: [Float]
weights = [0.75, 0.25]
```

This should be understood as follows:

```
Alice's grades:   3 and 2 -- The grade 3 weighted with 75% and the grade 2 with 25%
Bob's grades:     4 and 6 -- The grade 4 weighted with 75% and the grade 6 with 25%
Charlie's grades: 2 and 3 -- The grade 2 weighted with 75% and the grade 3 with 25%
David's grades:   1 and 4 -- The grade 1 weighted with 75% and the grade 4 with 25%
```

I wrote a function which calculates the `averageGrade` for one student:

```
averageGrade :: [Float] -> [Int] -> Float
```

I have to accomplish a function according to this type:

```
allStudents :: [String] -> [[Int]] -> [Float] -> [(String, Float)]
```

This function should give tuples of each person with their average grade such as:

```
[("Alice", 2.75), ("Bob", 4.5), etc....]
```

The calculation is made by `averageGrade (weights) ([Specific Grades])`, e.g.

```
averageGrade (weights) ([3,2])
```

if I want to calculate it for Alice.

How can I iterate over a list without going through it via `head` and `tail` (because recursion is not allowed)?

Comment: I assume using other functions that are implemented with recursion is allowed? Otherwise this would not be possible. Bear in mind that you have `map`/`foldr`/`foldl` available.

Comment: In particular, `map` should be incredibly useful here. `map function list` gives the result of applying `function` to each element of `list`.

Comment: Probably `zipWith` too.

Comment: Isn’t there a `zipWith3`?

Comment: @Elmex80s Yes, but I'm not so sure it's useful here? We seem to have two lists of the same length (values per student), and another list of a different length (values per problem).

Comment: Taking a step back: why are the names and grades separate in the first place? Where are they coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are prohibited to use recursion, that means that you should use some standard functions like `foldl`, `foldr`, `map`, `zip` and so on.

As you have `averageGrade` function to process grades of a student, then you can process a list of such with `map` like this:

```
map (averageGrade weights) grades
```

It will apply `averageGrade weights` function on each element of list one by one, and return you a list of results, namely, the list of average grades for every student.

So now, when you processed the data of all students, all you need is just pair each student name with appropriate average grade. You can use `zip` function for that:

```
allStudents :: [String] -> [[Int]] -> [Float] -> [(String, Float)]
allStudents names grades weights = zip names $ map (averageGrade weights) grades
```

You can test it here: https://repl.it/@Yuri12358/so-zip

Answer (score 2):

So you want

```
allStudents  :: [String] -> [[Int]] -> [Float]            -> [(String, Float)]
```

which is not all that different from

```
allStudents2 :: [String] -> [Float] -> [[Int]]            -> [(String, Float)]
```

and you have

```
averageGrade ::             [Float] ->  [Int]  ->  Float
```

such that

```
averageGrade (weights ::    [Float]) :: [Int]  ->  Float
```

and since

```
map (foo ::                               a    ->   b      ) 
                           ::          [  a  ] -> [ b   ]
```

we have

```
map (averageGrade weights) ::          [[Int]] -> [Float]
```

and

```
map (averageGrade weights) (grades :: [[Int]]) :: [Float]
```

and [the one last missing piece to the puzzle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5Bc%5D%20-%3E%20%5Bb%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%20%28c%2Cb%29%20%5D&scope=set%3Astackage) is

```
_ ::            [ c    ]  ->                      [ b   ] -> [( c    , b    )]
```

such that

```
_ (names ::     [String]) ::                      [ b   ] -> [(String, b    )]
```